# Java Mail Api send email failed

Tags: java, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
      nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com/108.177.125.108 (port 465) from /:: (port 58929): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

code snippet

```
public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
   this.user = user;
   this.password = password;

   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
   props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
   props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
   session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
}
```

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: to prevent unauthorized acces to your email  you need to log into your account at Gmail.com,  then open another tab and go the Less Secure Apps Setting, and select “Turn on”.

Comment: Already do this but not working

Comment: be sure you are connected to internet while sending email

Comment: internet is working fine

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me:**

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Email {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String username = "sender email address";
        final String password = "sender email password";

        Properties props  = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port","587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, 
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
        });           

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender email address"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("receiver email address"));
            message.setSubject("First");
            message.setContent("<h1>hello</h1>","text/html");
            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Email has been sent succesfully...");   
        }
        catch(MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


    }
}
```

Replace the sender/receiver email address/password  with the right one.